# TypeScript Node.js package

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, package

I am making a node.js package found [here](https://github.com/DusterTheFirst/Mechan)

Development is going well, all except one thing. All of my code is in one file, [index.ts](https://github.com/DusterTheFirst/Mechan/blob/master/Mechan/index.ts).

I googled with no luck on how to separate the classes into different files and then be able to put them all together as a package in the end, while keeping the typescript types and all.

There are many ways to do it, but then they break IntelliSense (the items do not show up). Due to the whole reason I am using typescript is to have IntelliSense, and somewhat inline documentation, that is not a viable option.

Any help would be appreciated.

SOLUTION:

./Help/HelpModule.ts

```
export enum HelpMode {
    /**
     * Disable the automatic help command.
     */
    Disabled,
    /**
     * Use the automatic help command and respond in the channel the command is used.
     */
    Public,
    /**
     * Use the automatic help command and respond in a private message.
     */
    Private
}
```

./index.ts

```
export * from './Help/HelpMode';
```

Comment: What IDE are you using? Visual Studio Code has excellent TypeScript support and it understands the TypeScript module system out of the box.

Comment: @Thilo I use VS2017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To split out your code into multiple files you must first move your functions into a new file, export them, then import them into your new file.

For example

```
//index.ts
function fooA() { .. }
function fooB() { .. }
```

If we want to split foo B into its own file. We do:

```
//index.ts
import { fooB } from "./fooB";
function fooA() { .. }
```

And the other file would be

```
//fooB.ts
export function fooB() { .. }
```

Comment: can i do the same with the classes?

Comment: would I be able to set it as an export from my index.ts?